# distinct and order by in json_agg and json_build_object postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my Query:

```
select cm.control_id,cm.control_name,
(select json_agg
 (distinct jsonb_build_object
  ('question_id',qm.question_id,'question_code',qm.question_description,'option_type_id',qm.option_type_id,'options',
   (select json_agg(json_build_object('qo_id',qo.qo_id,'option',qo.option,'ans',aad.question_option_id))
    FROM question_option qo, audit_answer_detail aad 
    WHERE qo.question_id = qm.question_id and aad.audit_header_id = ah.audit_header_id and aad.question_id = qo.question_id)))) 
    as question 
    from audit_process_detail apd 
    inner join audit_header ah on ah.audit_header_id = 79 
    inner join compliance_process_control cpc on apd.audit_header_id = ah.audit_header_id and apd.process_id = cpc.process_id 
    inner join control_master cm on cpc.control_id = cm.control_id 
    inner join compliance_control_question ccq  on cm.control_id = ccq.control_id and ah.compliance_id = ccq.compliance_id 
    inner join question_master qm on ccq.question_id = qm.question_id 
    where qm.is_active = B'1' group by cm.control_id,cm.control_name
```

And this is my output:

```
[{
    "control_id": 13,
    "control_name": "Access Management",
    "question": [
        {
            "options": [
                {
                    "ans": null,
                    "qo_id": 75,
                    "option": "YES"
                },
                {
                    "ans": null,
                    "qo_id": 76,
                    "option": "NO"
                }
            ],
            "question_id": 38,
            "question_code": "Have you implemented an authentication mechanism in your application, system and devices?",
            "option_type_id": 4
        },
        {
            "options": [
                {
                    "ans": null,
                    "qo_id": 77,
                    "option": "YES"
                },
                {
                    "ans": null,
                    "qo_id": 78,
                    "option": "NO"
                }
            ],
            "question_id": 39,
            "question_code": "Do you have a procedure defined by your IT team to provide user credentials to your clients upon request?",
            "option_type_id": 4
        },
        {
            "options": [
                {
                    "ans": null,
                    "qo_id": 79,
                    "option": "YES"
                },
                {
                    "ans": null,
                    "qo_id": 80,
                    "option": "NO"
                }
            ],
            "question_id": 40,
            "question_code": "Can you assure that only your IT team and the client project team have access to the client's confidential information?",
            "option_type_id": 4
        },
        {
            "options": [
                {
                    "ans": null,
                    "qo_id": 373,
                    "option": "YES"
                },
                {
                    "ans": null,
                    "qo_id": 374,
                    "option": "NO"
                }
            ],
            "question_id": 187,
            "question_code": "Whether use of any privileges in information system environment is restricted, controlled and managed using proper authorization process",
            "option_type_id": 4
        },
        {
            "options": [
                {
                    "ans": null,
                    "qo_id": 375,
                    "option": "YES"
                },
                {
                    "ans": null,
                    "qo_id": 376,
                    "option": "NO"
                }
            ],
            "question_id": 188,
            "question_code": "Whether users and support employees have access to information and application system functionalities in line with the stated topic-specific access control policy. ‎",
            "option_type_id": 4
        },
        {
            "options": [
                {
                    "ans": null,
                    "qo_id": 377,
                    "option": "YES"
                },
                {
                    "ans": null,
                    "qo_id": 378,
                    "option": "NO"
                }
            ],
            "question_id": 189,
            "question_code": "Whether strict controls are in place to restrict access to ‎program source libraries.",
            "option_type_id": 4
        },
        {
            "options": [
                {
                    "ans": null,
                    "qo_id": 437,
                    "option": "YES"
                },
                {
                    "ans": null,
                    "qo_id": 438,
                    "option": "NO"
                }
            ],
            "question_id": 219,
            "question_code": "Whether the utility programme restricted and strictly controlled in its ability to override system and application controls?",
            "option_type_id": 4
        }
]
```

If the data in the table changes, the order of listing changed.I want to order it by the question id.
It says Distinct and json_agg cannot be in the same thing, What should I do? I want to add order by in first json_agg where distinct is present.Should I need to change the query format or we can clear it in this query itself?